# .change() function not working

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have a form called #change_product, where I add with this code a select via jquery:

```
var strCategory = '<div class="rowEl"><label>Label<span>*</span></label><div class="select"><select name="product_category" class="mandatory"><option value=""></option>'; 

$.each(product.categoryCdVersion, function(category, cdVersion){
    strCategory += '<option value="'+cdVersion+'">'+category+'</option>';
});
strFascia += '</select></div>';           
$("#product_options").prepend(strCategory);
```

When the product_category select is used, i need to change an input type called cdVersion I've put inside the form.

```
 <form id="change_product" class="usersetting change_product" action="/"> 
        ...
        <input type="hidden" name="cdVersion" value=""/>
        ...

 </form>
```

This is what I do in

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(function() {  

        ...
        $('#change_product').find('select[name="product_category"]').change(function() {
            var cdVersionFromCategory = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
            $("#change_product").find('input[name="product_cdVersione"]').val(cdVersionFromCategory);
        });
        ...

     });            
});
```

but I always get the first value of the options list in cdVersion, and I can't see anything I log with console.log inside the change function, so there must be an error, what do you think? Is it because the select is created after the document is loaded? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume select is a multi select list?
try:

```
$(function() {
    $('#change_product').find('select[name="product_category"]').change(function(event) {
        var selectedOption = $(event.target).find("option:selected");
        // do stuff with options
    });
});
```